# Variables get reset after redirection [SCALA-PLAY]

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to play framework. 
In the given code invoking /connect get connected to salesforce and redirects to /getObjects, but after redirection salesforce connection variable "x" gets null again.

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}

class ApplicationController extends Controller {
  var x:connectBase = null
  def connect(uname: String, pwd: String) = Action {
    val con = SalesForceDump(uname, pwd)
    con.connect
    if (!con.isConnected) {
      Ok("error")
    }
    else {
      x = connectBase(con)
      Ok("user:").withSession("connected" -> uname)
      Redirect(routes.ApplicationController.getObjects)
      // Ok("done")
    }
  }

  def getObjects = Action { request =>
    println(x.connection) // this gets null
    request.session.get("connected").map { user =>
      println("Hello " + user)
      Ok(x.connection.getAllObjects.mkString(","))
    }.getOrElse {
      Unauthorized("Oops, you are not connected")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using the injected router (default configuration of a Play application).

A new instance of the controller is created for every request, so it's "expected" that you lose the content of your variable.

To keep it between requests, you should declare your controller as a singleton using this annotation:

```
@javax.inject.Singleton
class ApplicationController extends Controller {
  ...
}
```

However, you might be missing some point. That variable will be shared between all of the users (connected or not) that access to your application. Moreover, if you host several instances of your application, you will not have this variable replicated over all your applications instances. You might get into trouble because of that.

Play applications are usually meant to be stateless, that means they don't store any variable that they reuse across requests. If you need to store things, you may consider:

- using a database;
- using a cookie for "small" data that are user-specific.